# Extract both certificates and response payload from URL with Clojure

Tags: http, clojure, x509certificate

I'm trying to extract both the certificate from an URL and its payload response in a single request.
My code right now looks like this:

```
(s/defn get-server-leaf-certificate
  [url :- s/Str]
  (let [conn (.openConnection url)]
    (with-open [_ (.getInputStream conn)]
      (some-> (.getServerCertificates conn) first))))
```

With this implementation I can extract the certificate but how can I also extract the response from this request?

Comment: I'd try replacing that `_` with a proper name and just reading the stream into a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I got this to work:

```
(:import (java.net URI)
           (java.io BufferedReader))

(s/defn retrieve-dynamic-response-from-psp!
  [url :- s/Str]
  (let [conn (.openConnection (io/as-url url))
        _ (.setReadTimeout conn (config/read-timeout))
        _ (.setRequestProperty conn "Accept" "application/json")]
    (with-open [is (.getInputStream conn)]
      (let [response-code (.getResponseCode conn)
            certificate (some-> (.getServerCertificates conn) first)
            reader ^BufferedReader (io/reader is)
            raw-response-body (-> reader line-seq first)]
        (if-not (and (>= response-code 200) (< response-code 300))
          (throw "Error retrieving response")
          [raw-response-body certificate])))))
```